# erro de chamada de classe

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, classes, namespace

bom dia a todos!! 
galera, eu estou voltando a mexer com php puro e me deparei com um erro meio besta, mas que não estou sabendo resolver...o erro é :

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\PDO\index.php:5 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in 
C:\xampp\htdocs\PDO\index.php on line 5
```

eu vou postar as 2 classes que eu chamo:

```
<?php 

namespace classes\NewConex;

class NewConex{

    protected $Conn;

    protected function Conex(){ $this->$Conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;port=;dbname=pdo', 'root', '');  return $this; }

    protected function Dstroy(){ $this->$Conn=NULL; }

}
```

e a outra é a crud:

```
<?php 
namespace classes\Crud;
use classes\NewConex;

class Crud{

     function __construct($x = array()) 
        { 
           $x = new NewConex; 
           $x->$Conn;
        }

    public function insert(){} 
}
```

e estou chamando essas duas no index.php da seguinte forma:

```
<?php 
require_once("classes/NewConex.php");
require_once("classes/crud.php");

$z = new Crud();
```

o que está errado aqui pessoal? obrigado pela atenção!!

Comment: Recomendo adicionar a mensagem de erro inteira na pergunta, somente com a parte que colocou não temos informação alguma. Aliás, não faz muito sentido definir todos os campos de `NewConex` como `protected`. Talvez esse seja o problema no seu código.

Answer (score 1):

1. Uso de [namespaces](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.namespaces.php)
2. Encapsulamento de atributos de classes [Visibilidade no PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.oop5.visibility.php)
3. Uso de propriedade de classes - [veja](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.oop5.basic.php)
4. [Métodos Mágicos - Destrutores](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.oop5.decon.php#language.oop5.decon.destructor)

---

### Uso de namespaces

#### Em `NewConex`:

Para usar a classe `PDO` (que é global do PHP) dentro do seu namespace, neste caso `classes\NewConex`, você precisa inserir um barra invertida '**\**' antes do nome da classe para indicar que essa classe (`PDO`) não pertence ao escopo de seu namespace, mas sim, ao escopo global. Ou seja, *a classe não está inserida no seu namespace*.

Dessa forma,

```php
$this->Conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;port=;dbname=pdo', 'root', '');
```

torna-se

```php
$this->Conn = new \PDO('mysql:host=localhost;port=;dbname=pdo', 'root', '');  
# Repare na barra ^^ aqui.
```

#### Em `Crud`:

A classe `NewConex` pertence ao namespace `classes\NewConex`.
A classe `Crud` pertence ao namespace `classes\Crud`.  Portanto, as duas classes pertencem a namespaces diferentes. 
E quando você quer usar uma classe que pertence a outro namespace (ex: `NewConex`) em um namespace (ex: `classes\Crud`), você precisa usar

Ao invés de

```php
use classes\NewConex;
```

digite,

```php
use classes\NewConex\NewConex;
```

pois, o "endereço" ou **nome** completo da classe `NewConex` é `classes\NewConex\NewConex;`.

Obs: Eu acredito que o que você queria era as duas classes num namespace chamado `classes`. Sendo assim, os nomes dos namespaces não poderiam conter os nomes das classes. Seriam, portanto, `namespace classes;`. E quando fosse usá-las, usaria assim `use classes\NewConex` e `use classes\Crud`.  Mas se eu estiver errado, desconsidere essa observação.

#### Em `index.php`

Para usar `Crud`, inclua uma referência para a classe

```php
use classes\Crud\Crud;
```

ou referencie-a com seu nome completo

```php
$z = new classes\Crud\Crud();
```

---

### Encapsulamento de atributos de classes

Em `Crud`, você tenta utilizar a propriedade `$Conn` de `classes\NewConex\NewConex`. Porém, essa propriedade possui [visibilidade](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.oop5.visibility.php) **protected**, o que significa que ela só pode ser acessada e manipulada pela própria classe que a declara (`classes\NewConex\NewConex`) e eventuais classes que a herda (veja [herança de objetos/classes](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.oop5.inheritance.php) se tiver dúvidas).

Como `classes\Crud\Crud` não herda `classes\NewConex\NewConex`, ela não tem acesso a propriedade `Conn` de `NewConex`.

Duas opções para corrigir isso é tornar `Conn` **pública**

```php
public $Conn;
```

ao invés de,

```php
protected $Conn;
```

ou criar um método *getter* para `Conn`

```php
protected $Conn;
//...

public function get_conn() 
{
    return $this->Conn;
}
```

---

### Uso de propriedade de classes

*Deveria ter colocado este tópico antes do segundo.*

- Na declaração de uma propriedade você inclui `$`. Ex: `public $Conn`.
- No uso, você não inclui `$`. Exs: `$this->Conn`;  `$NewConex->Conn`.

---

### Métodos Mágicos - Destrutores

Eu acredito que com o método `classes\NewConex\NewConex\Dstroy()`, você quis criar um [método mágico destrutor](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.oop5.decon.php#language.oop5.decon.destructor) da classe `classes\NewConex\NewConex`. Se este for o caso, o correto era chamá-lo de `__destruct()` e não `Dstroy()`.

Comment: consegui, problema resolvido, muito obrigado!!!!!!

Comment: Que bom que conseguiu.  Disponha. Se tiver mais dúvidas, poste aqui para a comunidade ou eu te ajudar. 
Se você acha que minha resposta solucionou seu problema, clica no "vezinho" que está na esqueda da minha resposta (veja aqui [como aceitar uma resposta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta) para ajudar a comunidade. Obrigado